# How do I send and receive a string using ajax and express.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I need to send a string to a function on the server. Then send a string to the client after the server function is done.

cleint

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/text',
    data: { q:document.getElementById("text").value},
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

server

```
 app.post('/text', function(req, res) {
   console.log(data.q);
 });
 app.listen(1337);
```

This returns this error on client

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/text. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Why does this not log the text to the terminal and how do I send a string back to the success function?

Comment: Google about Access Control origen. Your client doesnt run on the same Website does it? You need to set the correct response headers for that case.

Comment: @user2415266 I am running this using a node script and a html file opened in chrome this will not be used in any production anything. No error occurs if I don't try to log data.q.

Comment: Essentially, the issue is that you're attempting to retrieve data from a server which resides on a different domain, as in, your website needs to be on the same server it's trying to retrieve data from, or it throws the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the bodyParser module with Express in your server file.

```
npm install body-parser
```

> The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares. All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed body or provide an error to the callback.
>   A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body).

On your server file, change the code as follow :

```
  var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
  var app=require('express');
  app.use(bodyParser());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
  }));      
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.post('/text', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.q);
  });
  app.listen(1337);
```

On you client file, add the datatype JSON to you ajax request and change the url to '/text'

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/text',
dataType: "json",
data: { q:document.getElementById("text").value},
success: function (response) {

},
error: function () {
}
});
```

Comment: `body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares app.js:11:11` so it returns a error `app.use(bodyParser());`

Comment: I got the point, i have edited my answer, would you check now please